# Access to admin page links not given to publisher

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this sessions logic if user is not admin so he don't have to get access admin page function is it good sessions logic? approach or should i use another one please guide me further.LOOK this index page i have some links have to access the other member then admin and all links for admin please tell me  what links is in url component you are using

```
  <?php
  include "config.php";
  session_start();
  if( (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['type'])) ){
    header('location:login.php'); 
 }
if($_SESSION['type'] != 'Administrator')
{
    header('location:index.php');
 }
?>

  index.php
 <?php
include "config.php";
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
{
 header('location:login.php');
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Article</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Categories</a>
         <?php
          if($_SESSION['type']=='Administrator'){ 
          ?>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Media</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item">tempelate</a>
      <a href="test.php" class="list-group-item">Setting</a>
          <?php
          }else{ 
          ?>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Profile</a>
          <?php
          } 
          ?>
      <a href="logout.php" class="list-group-item">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the user to not get access to the admin page, a slightly more robust check would be to probably first ascertain whether the current page is indeed `admin.php`. If yes, then `type` can be verified so as to know if it's indeed set to `Administrator`, before the access can be granted.

If it is not set or is set to something else, then the user may be taken back to `index.php` page.

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    session_start();


    $url_components =  explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $current_url    =  $url_components[count($url_components) - 1];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location:login.php'); 
    }

    if(!($current_url == 'admin.php' 
            && isset($_SESSION['type']) 
            && $_SESSION['type'] == 'Administrator')){
        header('location:index.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: i have added the index.php code please check i am confused in explode what scrpt name and current_url? what thing i use

Comment: [`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) gives you the complete path of the URL that the script is being run from. For instance: `http://localhost/project/file.php`. We split this using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) based on `/` to get `file.php` in the `$current_url` variable. Now, if `$current_url` is `admin.php`, the rest of the checks can be made to know whether the access must be granted or not. If you still feel confused, try `print_r` or `echo` on each of those variables and you could see how they're being used.

Comment: let me checking :)

Comment: check above i have add this code but it does not getting to access the test.php page which is must be granted to administrator

Comment: `$_SERVER['http://localhost/test/index.php']` - this is incorrect. Please let it just be `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and then, in order to test, try to go to `http://localhost/test/index.php` or `http://localhost/test/test.php` or `http://localhost/test/test.php` by typing the address or clicking a hyperlink. Try that for the different user types and you should only be allowed to `admin.php` when the type is `Administrator`.

Comment: brother listen i have one main page which is index.php . and i have two portion in this main page like above if i have 5 links to other pages i just given to show 3 links if users is other then admin and if he is admin 5 links shown. i don't have admin.php page i have same page index.php for admin and other user then admin

Comment: Well, what you're now asking is very different from what the initial question was.... So, I presume your code is presently working fine and you want to know whether it is still good? My answer to that would be, that it is fine as far as displaying the links is concerned, but not enough for protecting the pages if someone simply accesses them by typing in a direct address. For instance, try logging in with some use type other than `admin`. They'll not be shown the link to `test.php`. However, when you type `test.php` directly in the address bar, nothing would step them either..

Comment: this error is comming when i echoing Notice: Undefined index: localhost/test in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 6
$url_components$current_url

Comment: Therefore, the code in the answer above can be added (maybe with little modifications) at the top of every page in your application to protect the important pages against undesired accesses.

Comment: i have tested this . if i login other then admin and put direct test.php which is admin access page link only . i can't get access it move to index.php page. but i wana know is it fine method or not :) you help me alot thankyou i need suggestions about it

Comment: Well, thank you. If that's the case, then I think and hope that it should be fine now.

Comment: <?php
    include "config.php";
    session_start();

    if( (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['type'])) ){
        header('location:login.php'); 
    }

    if($_SESSION['type'] != 'Administrator')
    {
        header('location:index.php');
    }
?> please check this one it not giving the access to test.php if logged person is not admin even if directly type in address bar so can  i use this?

Comment: Looks fine to me.